# Trouble with encoding and urllib

Tags: python, encoding, urllib

I'm loading web-page using urllib. Ther eis russian symbols, but page encoding is 'utf-8'

## 1

```
pageData = unicode(requestHandler.read()).decode('utf-8')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 262: ordinal not in range(128)
```

## 2

```
pageData = requestHandler.read()
soupHandler = BeautifulSoup(pageData)
print soupHandler.findAll(...)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 340-345: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: s/dencode/encode/ ; assuming this is just a typo.

Comment: Have you worked through [these tips](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit)?

Comment: In real code there is 'decode'. Just a typing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first snippet, the call `unicode(requestHandler.read())` tells Python to convert the bytestring returned by `read` into `unicode`: since no code is specified for the conversion, `ascii` gets tried (and fails).  It never gets to the point where you're going to call `.decode` (which would make no sense to call on that unicode object anyway).

Either use `unicode(requestHandler.read(), 'utf-8')`, *or* `requestHandler.read().decode('utf-8')`: either of these should produce a correct unicode object *if* the encoding is indeed `utf-8` (the presence of that `D0` byte suggests it may not be, but it's impossible to guess from being shown a single non-ascii character out of context).

`print`ing Unicode data is a different issue and requires a well configured and cooperative terminal emulator -- one that lets Python set `sys.stdout.encoding` on startup.  For example, on a Mac, using Apple's Terminal.App:

```
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'UTF-8'
```

so the printing of Unicode objects works fine here:

```
>>> print u'\xabutf8\xbb'
«utf8»
```

as does the printing of utf8-encoded byte strings:

```
>>> print u'\xabutf8\xbb'.encode('utf8')
«utf8»
```

but on other machines only the latter will work (using the terminal emulator's own encoding, which you need to discover on your own because the terminal emulator isn't telling Python;-).

Comment: Yeah, now script doesn't fail during page decoding, but in beautiful soup I get same error.

Comment: @Ockonal, BeautifulSoup 3.0.8 works fine with unicode data (avoid 3.1.0!).  I bet your problem is with the `print`ing, not with BeautifulSoup itself.

Comment: Yeah, damn =) I used printing for searching my mistake. And it was near page-data decoding. Thanks, without printing this works well.

Answer (score 1):

If `requestHandler.read()` delivers a UTF-8 encoded stream, then

```
pageData = requestHandler.read().decode('utf-8')
```

will decode this into a Unicode string (at which point, as Dietrich Epp noted correctly), the `unicode()` call is not necessary anymore.

If it throws an exception, then the input is obviously not UTF-8-encoded.

Comment: At which point the call to `unicode` can be removed, as it's redundant.

Comment: Yeah, there is an error. I tried both: encode/decode, the same error.

Comment: There isn't error during decoding of page data. Only near beautiful soup code.

Comment: Could you update your question and show the actual error then?